# Selenium Webdriver Java-> Click Facebook share button for the post i want

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation, automated-tests

I am facing the problem in identifying and clicking on share button for a facebook post. 
Suppose, i have 4 posts on my Facebook page. I am looking to click share and then 'share...' from small pop window for any of the 4 posts i want.

I have tried several methods but it is not working. Can you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML, code trials and errors (if any)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new. If you use python and you can click on the first share, then when the window pops up I would suggest to use your mouse to click on the second share.
Try:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

    time.sleep(2)
    mouse = Controller()
    mouse.position = (972, 371)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Of course 972, 371 is an example, you will have to find the exact point where "share button" is

Comment: Thanks Alessio for describing it by using python. I am using Java so is there any way to do it using Java?